# Multiplayer game: how to sync FPS of different PC?

Tags: c#, network-programming

i'm wondering how can i "sync" the speed (obviously, to the less fast) of different PC ? 
My is a 2d racing game, written in C# + SDL.NET.
How to "move" object on screen at the "same" speed on all PCs sending "state" variable only 3 times per second (for instance) ?
Thanks

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) is the friendliest article I've read on the matter. You should look at all the game physics articles from this guy ([GafferOnGames](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/))

> [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)
>
> Even an RK4 integrator is sensitive to
>   the amount of time you step when
>   integrating. Decouple your physics
>   timestep from the display framerate so
>   that your simulation behaves exactly
>   the same way each time it is run.

...then continue with this one:

> [What every programmer needs to know
>   about game networking](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/)
>
> A brief overview of the history of PC
>   multiplayer games. Discover how RTS
>   games were able to synchronize
>   thousands of units over a 28k modem,
>   and how first person shooters hide lag
>   with client side prediction and
>   latency compensation.

Hope you'll find it as eye-opening as I did.